# Error 403 access denied in custom post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to update all of my custom post in wordpress admin but not all post can updated. Most of all post cannot be updated saying, Error 403.

What can I do about this, my account that I use is already a admin.

Comment: This could be any of a number of things:

1. Does the user you have logged in have permission to edit the posts in question?

2. Sometimes there may be a conflicting plugin.

3. `.htaccess` file might be causing the conflict

Comment: What should i do? @TomaszFoster

Comment: Let's rule out as many different things as possible.
- First, I would make sure that whoever you're logged in as is an administrator that has access to edit the posts.
- Second, try disabling all plugins and seeing if you're able to update your custom posts. You may need to re-enable one or two plugins to be able to make this work.
- If those two don't resolve it, we can at least cross those off our list. 403 typically points to some kind of permission issue so we should know generally where to look.

Comment: can you share the your register_post type code with us so we can take a look at